# data transfer -mysql and sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I'm try to get data from mysql server to ms sql server.I have done this processes in localhost(Using ODBC connector).

But now those server are hosting as an online data bases.Can anyone tell me the way of doing this?

I think i can't use odbc connectors for online server.

Please help me to fix this issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to use ODBC connection. You can use this step by step approach and if you have your own mysql server(be it online or anywhere else), then it hardly a concern since you have all the credentials. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29106/Migrate-MySQL-to-Microsoft-SQL-Server
References : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811006.aspx

But if you still dont want to use ODBC connection, then there are few tools available in the market like data loader(http://www.dbload.com/)